# Check if a column in a 2D list contains the same values

Tags: python

For example, `a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]` has 3 columns with the same values

I'm trying to check How can I do this without using `numpy` arrays? I essentially need help iterating over columns instead of rows.

Comment: What's the expected result? `True` because you have a column with the same values in all rows? `3` because you have three of them? Something else?

Comment: Why not just use use numpy.unique with axis set to 1? Examples are found here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html

Comment: @Mureinik 3 because I have three of them

Comment: Is the number of rows fixed? Is the number of columns same in all the rows? Is the number of columns fixed?

Comment: It is a square matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over the columns with a loop, and for each column check the all the row values are equal to the first rows:

```py
def numUniformColumns(mat):
    cnt = 0
    for j in range(0, len(mat[0])):
        first = mat[0][j]
        uniform = True
        for i in range(1, len(mat)):
            if first != mat[i][j]:
                uniform = False
                break;

        if uniform:
            cnt += 1

    return cnt
```